# Azure Batch Service vs. Azure Databricks for Python Job

Tags: python, azure, databricks, azure-databricks, azure-batch

Let's say I have a Data Analysis Problem (e.g. csv data like Iris Dataset) where I want to do some data manipulation and processing with Pandas and Python. My Python Script is already written and each day when I receive a csv file, I want this data to be processed with my python script in the Azure cloud and the result will be written to an Azure Blob storage.

Now I have come across these links/approaches to solve this:

- [Run Python Scripts via Data Factory using Azure Batch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/tutorial-run-python-batch-azure-data-factory)
- [Run Databricks-Notebook activity in Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-databricks-notebook)
- [Run Python Scripts via Azure Databricks Python activity in Data Factory](https://azure.microsoft.com/de-de/resources/videos/azure-friday-execute-jars-and-python-scripts-on-azure-databricks-using-data-factory/)

Does anybody has some experience with both approaches to run a python script as described above and maybe recommendations and what to consider (Pros/Cons)?

Goal of this question: What approach to choose or would you prefer: a) **Azure Batch Service** or b) **Azure Databricks** and why?

Things to consider for choosing the appropriate service:

- price
- convenience of setting up solution
- monitoring possibilities
- possibilities to scale if data grows or script-logic gets more complex over time
- ease of integration with other services (e.g. storage)
- flexibility with regards to libraries and frameworks (e.g. let's say later on it might become a data science problem and I want to add some h2o machine learning models into my analysis pipeline)
- (maybe more I did not consider ...?)

Comment: Sorry, but this type of question is specifically not on topic for this site.

Answer (score 3):

It is difficult to answer your question since the volume and complexity of your file and transformations as well as the financial constraints/time to execute are not described (e.g how many rows you have and columns?), I would suggest you take a look at data architecture technologies:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/data-guide/technology-choices/batch-processing

it will depend on several factor as described in Key selection criteria and capability matrix.

Personally I would use an Azure function to process the CSV and upload it to blob storage for simple CSV processing otherwise I would go for Data Factory.

For azure functions solution, you can divide functions in your python scripts and run them as separate orchestrated functions or your design pattern (chaining or fan out/in): main advantage is modularity and cost with serverless benefits:

[image]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/quickstart-python-vscode

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview?tabs=csharp